# Padding-Top and Padding-Bottom Not Working

Tags: html, css

For some reason padding-top and padding-bottom are not working for my #functions div.

I can't seem to figure out what is canceling out the CSS to cause this, and for some reason padding-left and padding-right work fine.

I want the #functions div to look like this:

[image: Intended Design of #Vocational]

Is there something wrong with my HTML or CSS? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
    src: url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
  .clearfix:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#calltoaction {
  background-image: url("calltoactionbackground.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#calltoaction p {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  width: 500px;
}
#functions {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#functions p {
  color: #62CE9C;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  color: #62CE9C;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
  color: #00AF78;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.hashtag {
  color:  #00AF78;
}
#hero {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#herotext {
  float: left;
}
#hero h1 {
  width: 470px;
}
#hero img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#hero p {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 500px;
}
input, select, textarea{
    color: #62CE9C;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #62CE9C;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #62CE9C !important;
}
 
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
#save {
  float: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
#savefood {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
#savefoodimage {
  float: right;
}
#savefoodtext {
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 290px; 
}
#savemoney {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savemoneyimage {
  float: left;
}
#savemoneytext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#savetime {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savetimeimage {
  float: left;
}
#savetimetext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#searchbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
#searchbutton {
  background-color: #28C787;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#searchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #00BE8B;
}
#tweetone {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetone img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetonetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
#tweettwo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweettwo img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweettwotext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
#tweetthree {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetthree img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetthreetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#vocational {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1120px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#vocational h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}
#vocational p {
  color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="herotext">
        <h1>Make the Most of your Food With Pantree</h1>
        <p>Pantree for iOS lets you search for recipes based on the ingredients you already have in your home.</p>
        <form id="form">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
          <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <img src="images/phone.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="functions">
      <div id=save>
        <div id="savemoney">
          <img id="savemoneyimage" src="images/savemoney.png"/>
          <div id="savemoneytext">
            <h2>Save Money</h2>
            <p>Pantree finds you recipes containing ingredients you already have in your home, saving you from unecessary trips to the grocery store.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="savefood">
          <img id="savefoodimage" src="images/savefood.png"/>
          <div id="savefoodtext">
            <h2>Save Food</h2>
            <p>Pantree keeps track of expiration dates, alerting you when food will go stale so you can use it before it goes bad.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="savetime">
          <img id="savetimeimage" src="images/savetime.png"/>
          <div id="savetimetext">
            <h2>Save Time</h2>
            <p>Pantree's built-in kitchen organizing system helps you monitor all of the food in your home, so figuring out what food you have is quick & easy.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="vocational">
      <h1>These Folks Could Use Pantree Every Day</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetone">
            <img src="images/tweetone.png"/>
            <div id="tweetonetext">
              <h3>Kat</h3>
              <h3>@devicat</h3>
              <p>I have no idea what to make for dinner. I am so bad at this game. <span class="hashtag">#adulting</span></p>
            </div>          
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweettwo">
            <img src="images/tweettwo.png"/>
            <div id="tweettwotext">
              <h3>Jack Falahee</h3>
              <h3>@RestingPlatypus</h3>
              <p>Dear Mom, How do I organize my kitchen? Love, me</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetthree">
            <img src="images/tweetthree.png"/>
            <div id="tweetthreetext">
              <h3>mason ryan</h3>
              <h3>@MasonTheManiac</h3>
              <p>Something in my fridge smells really bad.... <span class="hashtag">#cantfindit</span></p>
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="calltoaction">
      <h1>Manage your Kitchen, Effortlessly</h1>
      <p>Pantree makes it easy to find recipes, keep track of food, and organize your kitchen.</p>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to vertically centre using padding? Because that's generally not the way to do it. Search this site or google for methods of vertical centring for a vast range of options.

Comment: If you're going to use `display: table` read this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/ -- it's more of a system of elements (table-row, table column, etc. ) -- try using display `block` or `inline block` if you want to space elements using `padding`

Comment: @DBS I'm actually trying to change the the height of the white space between the elements in the div, not trying to vertically center. If you notice each of the modules has a good amount of breathing room before it ends, that's what I'm trying to do for this as well. It's just a design thing, I find it looks better, it's not about centering.

Comment: ****EDIT**** Woah! I just realized I wrongly called my #functions div #vocational, which is the name of a completely different div in my site! I am so sorry for the confusion, happy to see so many people could figure it out. I apologize for not catching that before I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using **CSS Flexbox**.

For Reference your CSS should be somewhat like:

```css
#savefood, #savemoney, #savetime {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#savefood {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Look at the snippet below (*use fullscreen to view it properly*):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
    src: url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
  .clearfix:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#calltoaction {
  background-image: url("calltoactionbackground.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#calltoaction p {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  width: 500px;
}
#functions {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#functions p {
  color: #62CE9C;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  color: #62CE9C;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
  color: #00AF78;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.hashtag {
  color:  #00AF78;
}
#hero {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#herotext {
  float: left;
}
#hero h1 {
  width: 470px;
}
#hero img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#hero p {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 500px;
}
input, select, textarea{
    color: #62CE9C;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #62CE9C;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #62CE9C !important;
}
 
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
#save {
  float: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
#savefood {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
#savefoodimage {
  float: right;
}
#savefoodtext {
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 290px; 
}
#savemoney {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savemoneyimage {
  float: left;
}
#savemoneytext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#savetime {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savetimeimage {
  float: left;
}
#savetimetext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#searchbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
#searchbutton {
  background-color: #28C787;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#searchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #00BE8B;
}
#tweetone {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetone img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetonetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
#tweettwo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweettwo img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweettwotext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
#tweetthree {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetthree img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetthreetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#vocational {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1120px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#vocational h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}
#vocational p {
  color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
}

#savefood,
#savemoney,
#savetime{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#savefood {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="herotext">
        <h1>Make the Most of your Food With Pantree</h1>
        <p>Pantree for iOS lets you search for recipes based on the ingredients you already have in your home.</p>
        <form id="form">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
          <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <img src="images/phone.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="functions">
      <div id=save>
        <div id="savemoney">
          <img id="savemoneyimage" src="http://placehold.it/200/200"/>
          <div id="savemoneytext">
            <h2>Save Money</h2>
            <p>Pantree finds you recipes containing ingredients you already have in your home, saving you from unecessary trips to the grocery store.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="savefood">
          <img id="savefoodimage" src="http://placehold.it/200/200"/>
          <div id="savefoodtext">
            <h2>Save Food</h2>
            <p>Pantree keeps track of expiration dates, alerting you when food will go stale so you can use it before it goes bad.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="savetime">
          <img id="savetimeimage" src="http://placehold.it/200/200"/>
          <div id="savetimetext">
            <h2>Save Time</h2>
            <p>Pantree's built-in kitchen organizing system helps you monitor all of the food in your home, so figuring out what food you have is quick & easy.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="vocational">
      <h1>These Folks Could Use Pantree Every Day</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetone">
            <img src="images/tweetone.png"/>
            <div id="tweetonetext">
              <h3>Kat</h3>
              <h3>@devicat</h3>
              <p>I have no idea what to make for dinner. I am so bad at this game. <span class="hashtag">#adulting</span></p>
            </div>          
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweettwo">
            <img src="images/tweettwo.png"/>
            <div id="tweettwotext">
              <h3>Jack Falahee</h3>
              <h3>@RestingPlatypus</h3>
              <p>Dear Mom, How do I organize my kitchen? Love, me</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetthree">
            <img src="images/tweetthree.png"/>
            <div id="tweetthreetext">
              <h3>mason ryan</h3>
              <h3>@MasonTheManiac</h3>
              <p>Something in my fridge smells really bad.... <span class="hashtag">#cantfindit</span></p>
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="calltoaction">
      <h1>Manage your Kitchen, Effortlessly</h1>
      <p>Pantree makes it easy to find recipes, keep track of food, and organize your kitchen.</p>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AlisonDyer My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

To apply padding make your element `display: block` and if your approach is to align it vertically. Make it `display: flex; align-items: center` and give a `height` to its parent element